# Reuse Allocated Class - Any Need to Release It?

Tags: objective-c

I'm pretty new to objective-c, I had a question. Is it ok to reuse the NSString_class that we allocated?

```
NSString_class = [NSString alloc]
```

Reuse like this:

```
str1 = [NSString_class initWithUTF8String: @"blah"]
str2 = [NSString_class initWithUTF8String: @"blah"]
```

and to release I dont have to release NSString_class right? Just the str1 and str2?

```
[str1 release]
[str2 release]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things....

It would be very unusual to split `alloc` and `init` into two different steps.

Your variable naming is also misleading.  The thing you get back from allocating an instance is an object that you assign to a pointer; it's not a "..._class".

That being said, you've called `alloc` once, which means you only have one object.  If you change its properties in order for `str2` to point to the string you want, you've changed it for `str1` as well.

Also, one `alloc` means +1 for the retain count, making two `release`s incorrect.

Comment: Ah thanks @Phil the reason I have it as two seperate is because I do this from ctypes. Do you, and doing `release` dpesmt return true or false so i dont know if Im doing it on the right one.

Comment: It's about the object, not the variables that point to it.  If you allocate an object, one `release` matches that allocation; it doesn't matter how many simple variables point to it.  (If you have those other variables point to **copies**, that's a different story.)